# Scheduling thousands of tasks with Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

We are considering to use Airflow for a project that needs to do thousands of calls a day to external APIs in order to download external data, where each call might take many minutes.

One option we are considering is to create a task for each distinct API call, however this will lead to thousands of tasks. Rendering all those tasks in UI is going to be challenging. We are also worried about the scheduler, which may struggle with so many tasks.

Other option is to have just a few parallel long-running tasks and then implement our own scheduler within those tasks. We can add a custom code into `PythonOperator`, which will query the database and will decide which API to call next.

Perhaps Airflow is not well suited for such a use case and it would be easier and better to implement such a system outside of Airflow? Does anyone have experience with running thousands of tasks in Airflow and can shed some light on pros and cons on the above use case?

Comment: This isn't a full answer to your question, but I'd think that if you're implementing a scheduler within a python process then there isn't much value add running that in airflow, as the scheduling wouldn't really apply (assuming I'm understanding correctly)

Comment: @qfwfq That's my thinking as well. Unless, we can run thousands of tasks in Airflow without any issues, in which case there would be no need for a separate scheduler.

Comment: So I don’t see a problem with thousands of tasks as long as they are grouped into DAGs appropriately. The only issue you might have is the timeliness of those tasks being executed. If you have specific SLA requirements you might have some tasks get queued for a while behind others. Is there a reason you are concerned about running this on a horiz scalable platform like Kube?

Answer (score 1):

One task per call would kill Airflow as it still needs to check on the status of each task at every heartbeat - even if the processing of the task (worker) is separate e.g. on K8s.

Not sure where you plan on running Airflow but if on GCP and a download is not longer than 9 min, you could use the following:

`task (PythonOperator) -> pubsub -> cloud function (to retrieve) -> pubsub -> function (to save result to backend).`

The latter function may not be required but we (re)use a generic and simple "bigquery streamer".

Finally, you query in a downstream AF task (PythonSensor) the number of results in the backend and compare with the number of requests published.

We do this quite efficiently for 100K API calls to a third-party system we host on GCP as we maximize parallelism. The nice thing of GCF is that you can tweak the architecture to use and concurrency, instead of provisioning a VM or container to run the tasks.